# Wordpress Error Establishing Database Connection

Tags: php, database, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have reinstalled phpAdmin (due to another issue) and updated wp-config with the correct names for DB, user name, password, etc, but now I cannot access the wordpress site (www.enablie.co.uk, www.enablie.co.uk/wp-admin or http://www.enablie.com/phpmyadmin).

I have tried adding the repair code

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

But still cannot access via : http://www.enablie.co.uk/wp-admin/maint/repair.php.

I am also getting this error when trying to access sql -

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

On Chrome is is showing a basic version of the site (broken styles) when not logged in, but get the EEDC as soon as try to log in.  On Safari I have the EEDC immediately.

I assume I have just done something stupid, but most errors seem to suggest naming errors in the config file which I know is not the case.  I have also checked the db still exists via mysql to ensure that there is not a problem there.

I assume that the re-install removed something from the overall settings that I now need to manually reconfigure, but I can't find any guidance that points me where to look so would appreciate some help on what I need to change.  Much appreciated!

Comment: **Error Establishing Database Connection** usually mean your database login details on `wp-config.php` are incorrect

Comment: also, PHPMYADMIN is a tool to access mysql databases not the database itself. So if you reinstall phpmyadmin no change need to be done to your db connection anywhere

Comment: I have checked wp-config.php and the database login details are all correct.  I wasn't expecting the reinstallation to cause an issue, but it is the only thing that I have changed and now have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted by instance and that seemed to fix the issue.